# OS X El Capitan nightmare

Tags: macos, downgrade

I installed El Capitan but did not like it, so I tried to uninstall following directions from [igeeksblog.com](http://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-downgrade-from-mac-os-x-el-capitan-to-yosemite/).  But when it came to reinstall the previous edition of OS X it only gave El Capitan as the option, so I reinstalled it, except now I cannot find any of my softwares or documents that were in my hard drive before I installed El Capitan.  Where did they go? Can I get them back?

The directions say to go to Disk Utility, startup disk, erase, type in Macintosh HD, select Mac OS Extended (Journaled), click erase.

Did this erase my entire hard drive?

Comment: Yes, erasing a hard drive will erase it. That's why the directions on igeeksblog afterwards propose to restore your stuff from a Time Machine backup.

Answer (score 7):

If you followed the directions in the how-to at igeeksblog you indeed erased your entire hard drive. Without a proper backup (e.g. Time Machine backup) all your apps and documents are gone.

If you don't have a backup, shut down your Mac immediately to decrease the probability to overwrite the erased data accidentally. Create a thumb drive/prepare an external drive with a bootable OS X system and install a data-recovery tool (e.g. Testdisk), boot your Mac to the external drive and try to recover as much of your data as possible to an external hard drive.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid so, yes.

The linked guide assumes that Step 3 will be to restore from a Time Machine drive.

It does seem singularly lacking in warnings, though the method itself is sound
- for one, that you need Time Machine, secondly that you need to have previously 'purchased' Yosemite otherwise it will not appear in App Store as an option, thirdly that as they are recommending an Internet Recovery, the OS you should have ended up with is the one that originally shipped with your computer; from where you then re-upgrade to any other previously owned OS.

As already mentioned by klanomoath; your next step is recovery.